# Detect long press on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I know how to simply detect a long press, but it detect after release. How can I detect the long press without releasing the finger?

This is the code I am using for long press now:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLongPressGesture()
}

func setupLongPressGesture() {
    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.ended` to `.began`.

From the documentation for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins (`UIGestureRecognizer.State.began`) when the number of allowable fingers (`numberOfTouchesRequired`) have been pressed for the specified period (`minimumPressDuration`) and the touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement (`allowableMovement`). The gesture recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves, and it ends (`UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended`) when any of the fingers are lifted.